# Equivalent of Javascript "match" in python

Tags: javascript, python, match

I have a method for extracting all the "words" from a string in javascript:

```
mystring.toLowerCase().match(/[a-z]+/g);
```

I'd like to convert that same logic (create an array of "words" from my string), but in python. How can I achieve that?

Comment: just a warning: your regex won't handle words with punctuation (in case that matters to you)

Comment: Hi Matt, it doesn't matter to me as I'm applying the same logic when matching words (ie for can't, I will match can and t against ["can","t"]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall'), which is similar to `String.prototype.match()`.

```
import re
regex = r"[a-z]+"
matches = re.findall(regex, strToScan)
```

Comment: another alternative might just be split (also dont use `str` as the  string variable name :P it makes bad habits ... +1 all the same)

Comment: Thanks! for the regex ur"[a-z]+", I get a syntax error... ?

Comment: @Stephane It doesn't for me.

Comment: how weird... python 3.4.2 ?

Comment: i  think `u` was removed in py3 (since all strings are unicode now except for the `bytes` string )

Comment: removing the u makes it all work! thanks much. Maybe you should edit your answer to make it compatible with both python 2 and 3

Comment: @Stephane Sure, will now.